# Bootstrap Search Bar adding "?search=" to router

Tags: jquery, vue.js, search, vue-router, bootstrap-vue

I added a toggle search bar ( guide/code here : https://www.solodev.com/blog/web-design/creating-a-toggled-search-bar.stml ) to my navbar in my `App.js` of my Vue project.

However, whenever I press "enter" after typing out search term (or click the search button without my own on click function), the search function adds `?search=` (+ the search term) to my router.
I have tried making a function that looks for the user pressing enter but that didn't work.

There is no explicit function in the code that seems to add to the router. And I cannot make it stop doing so without breaking the search box.

I'm looking for a way to either:

1. prevent the bootstrap search box from adding `?search=` to my router and instead follow my own routing method
   or
2. use vue-router to catch `?search=` at the end of the router and redirect to a search results page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can catch the search parameter(query url) in vue-router with this.$route.query.search for your example and when the user click the button just push the user with this query like this

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'your-route-name', query: { 'search': this.$route.query.search } })
```

Comment: Did you mean `this.$route.query.search` ?

Comment: @JamesAMohler yes sorry about typo. :)